Definition of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$, Hartshorne: I think something is wrong with $A_\mathfrak{p}$
Hartshorne constructs $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and at one point he goes like: for a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$, let $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ denote localization at $A$ at $\mathrm{p}$.
One slight problem. Localization is defined with respect to multiplicatively closed subsets.
Multiplicatively closed subsets contain 1.
The only ideal in a ring that contains 1 is the entire ring. Hence $\mathfrak{p} = A$ and $A_{\mathfrak{p}} = \mathrm{Quot}[A]$, field of fractions of $A$, which is not what he needed.
What I think happens here is that he lowkey just wants to make elements of ideal invertible somehow but has no other formal way to put it then to put "localization". Am I correct?

No. You have forgotten the definition of localization at a prime ideal. If $A$ is a (commutative, unital) ring and $p\subset A$ is a prime ideal, $A_p$ denotes the localization of $A$ at the multiplicatively closed subset $A\setminus p$. This is a local ring with maximal ideal $p$.

$A_\mathfrak{p}$ means the localization of $A$ at the multiplicative subset $A\setminus\mathfrak{p}$. You want to make every element of $A$ invertible except those in $\mathfrak{p}$.

Thankieeess!!!! I didn't know there is a special definition for localization at a prime ideal!

It's a common confusion. Especially because if a principal ideal $(p)$ is prime, then $A_{(p)}$ and $A_p$ mean different things!
